# Visual styles on WTL CreateSimpleToolbar()

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, toolbar, wtl

I have created WTL 8.1 project with the wizard. Visual styles are applied to menu and about dialog, but toolbar looks ugly. How can I make the toolbar look native in Vista/7?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Wizard-provided res\toolbar.bmp to a more appealing 32bpp one.